# HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF won't boot from USB drive. Solution

Tags: hardware, hp, desktop, bios, usb-boot

Can't get an HP 8200 Elite Small Form Factor to boot from USB.
(MP8200 Elite SFF PC)
BIOS version: J01 v02.15
ME Firmware version 7.1.3.1053
Tried on two different computers, with same BIOS version and the boot order list is not equal on the computers.

USB drive appears in BIOS "Device Configuration" list, but not in "Boot Order".

This is related to another thread, but I did not have enough reputation to answer on it.
[HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF won't boot from USB drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/352951/hp-compaq-8200-elite-sff-wont-boot-from-usb-drive)